# create class library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, class-library

I am using visual studio 2010 and tried to create a class library which I then use in an application that will create tasks using the TaskFactory and execute the class functions from the newly created class library. However I get the instance not defined errors in the application.

CLASS LIBRARY: 
  Assembly Name: GPStream   
  Root namespace: TFStream

Project with different classes:
  GPStream:
    gStream.vb,
    parserT.vb,
    insertDB.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class gStream
   Private Shared settings As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
   ' application configuration variables'

   Public Sub New()
      getConfigurations()
   End Sub
   ...
End Class


Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports TFStream
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks


Public Class Form1
    Private gp1 As TFStream.GPStream.gStream = New TFStream.GPStream.gStream()
    ...
End Class
```

I Do have it added as a reference.

Class library:   Assembly name GPStream, Root Namespace GPStream
                 Project name GPStream, Main Class gStream

Comment: Have you added a Reference to the assembly of the claas library using Add|Reference? Are all your classes under the same namespace, or the namespace can differ? If it differs from an object to another, you shall import all of the used namespace into your client class, that is, the class the uses the referenced class library.

Comment: Have you got the DLL included in the project that has the gstream class namespace within it?

Comment: I do have added as a reference

Comment: Also notice that you'd better type your private instance before you assign it a value, though type inference is possible from VB.NET 2008. And that you message seems to say that `GPStream.gstream` doesn't exist, while you tried to instantiate using `GPstream.gstream`, the 's' character casing differs from the one in the message and the one you used for instantiating your private field.

Comment: @Will The declaration is fine as it is. There is *no* implicit typing happening here. `As New X` is shorthand for `As X = New X`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Agreed! Besides, since the OP seems to say that he is a new comer to VB.NET, perhaps is it better to make sure he understands everything he does before taking shortcuts? Only my humble opinion here! This is worth what it's worth, that's all! =)

Comment: @vbNewbie: What is the type returned by GPStream.gstream`? You could write something like: `Private gp1 As GPStream = new GPStream.gstream()`, where `As GPStream` would be the type returned by the call of the initializer.

Comment: Tried that Will..Error: Type GPstream.gstream is not defined ====generate Class gstream

Comment: @vbNewbie: Then this means that the compiler can't find your class and gets confused between your namespace `GPStream` and your class `GPStream`. Try changing one of them and see if this solves the problem, while updating your code adequately to reflect the changes made. Otherwise, a code sample of your GPStream class shall be necessary along with your `gstream` class.

Comment: Please see edits for new code...tried different combinations and about to give up.Thanks for all responses

Comment: @vbNewbie: Please take an eye out my answer. I just answered with a completely new example pulled from accounting in regards ro customers/suppliers and credit terms. This is hopefully a basic enough example to guide you through the understanding of namespaces.

Comment: +1 A kindness such as yours deserves this! =) Plus, if you asked, this means that other people may be helped with this question as well! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'll have it with a perhaps simpler sample which, I hope, will help you achieve your goal.

Take it we have a business entities project which we want to use within our WinForm project. We then have two projects, say within the same solution for simplicity sake.

1. WinFormApp (MyCompany.MyProject.WinFormApp.exe);
2. BusinessEntities (MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities.dll).

> *We shall take it as these assembly files contains the same assembly name and default namespace.*

The namespace of my WinFormApp project is: `MyCompany.MyProject.WinFormApp`
And: `MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities` for the class library. Let's begin with the class library which contains the two following classes:

1. Customer;
2. Supplier;
3. CreditTerms.

In accounting, these two are used from a different point of views which are `Account Receivable` for the Customer and `Account Payable` for the Supplier. Proper Namespace could be assigned to reflect this reality.

The Customer class shall look like this:

```
Imports MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities

Namespace AccountReceivable
    Public Class Customer
        Private _id As Integer
        Private _name As String
        Private _phoneNumber As Long
        Private _creditTerm As CreditTerm

        Public Sub New()
            Term = CreditTerm.None
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal pId As Integer _
                        , ByVal pName As String _
                        , ByVal pPhoneNumber As Long)
            _id = pId
            Name = pName
            PhoneNumber = pPhoneNumber
            Term = CreditTerm.None
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property Name As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) Then _
                    Throw New ArgumentNullException("Name")

                _name = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property PhoneNumber As Long
            Get
                Return _phoneNumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Long)
                _phoneNumber = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Term As CreditTerm
            Get
                Return _term
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As CreditTerm)
                _term = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then, the Supplier class:

```
Imports MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities ' Used for the CreditTerm Enum Property'

Namespace AccountPayable
    Public Class Supplier
        ' We will here consider having the same properties as Customer for simplicity.'
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And the CreditTerms enumeration which here can be assigned to both a Supplier from which we buy, and a Customer to which we sell. Under that perspective, this class could either be at the root of your project to illsutrate its common use.

```
Public Enum CreditTerm
    None
    N30
    N45
    N60
    N90
End Enum
```

Then, our WinFormApp project should look something similar to:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Imports MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities 'Indeed you have to add the reference...'
Imports MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities.AccountReceivable

Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private _netTerm As CreditTerm = CreditTerm.None
    Private _customer As Customer = New Customer()
    Private _supplier As AccountPayable.Supplier = New AccountPayable.Supplier()
    ...
End Class
```

Notice here that I have expressly imported the `MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities` and `MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities.AccountReceivable` to illsutrate the differences of namespace between the `CreditTerm` enumeration and the `Customer` class. Therefore, I have not imported the the `Supplier` class' namespace, which obliges me to point to the location where to find the class.

In the end, I could have had `MyCompany.MyProject.BusinessEntities.Customer` namespace to group everything that regards a customer under the same namespace while having the Customer class inside the Customer namespace. But then, even when importing the namespace, you would have to write the following:

```
Private _customer As Customer.Customer = New Customer.Customer()
```

Another thing comes to mind while writing. Try to build/generate/regenerate the class library, then add it as a reference. Perhaps your project where the class library is referenced can't find the binaries, except if you did reference it through a Project Reference.

Please feel free to ask any question about misunderstood details or so, or even to say I myself have perhaps misunderstood your question and concerns.

I really DO hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks you so much for all your efforts and this was truelly helpful. What I had done was deleted everything and started again and still was having issues and someone told me it was because some of the classes i was using had references to 2.0 framework controls etx. But anyway, I avoided using a library and just put 2 projects into one solution and it works fine now but I will use your example to recreate what I initially tries. thanks again.

Comment: not sure how but I would like to give you extra points for this

Comment: I thank you so much for your gratitude! When accepting the answer, you may as well upvote the answer. After this being done, there's no other way, except if it would have been a bounty. Another way would be to encourage friends of yours to upvote. Nevertheless, you comments here are by far more encouraging and valueable to me than virtual points! I thank you for your comments! Do not hesitate to write whenever I may help! I'll gladly do so when I can. =)

Answer (score 2):

Does the last `Imports` statement work? If so, that indicates that `GPStream.gstream` is a namespace, not a class. Your class probably has a different name or is nested inside that namespace (have you tried `GPStream.gstream.gstream`?).

Comment: class name GPStream namepace GPStream classname gstream

Comment: @vbNewbie I don’t understand that comment …

Comment: Sorry I was just giving the namespace and assembly name I see under project properties - Assembly name: GPStream   Root NameSpace = GPstream   .....and the main class is called gstream

Comment: @vbNewbie In that case the `Imports` statement should already fail to compile.

Comment: @vbNewbie: If you called a class the same as the namespace, the language might get confused between which to address. In this circumstance, you perhaps should write this: `GPStream.GPStream.gstream` where the first `GPStream` refers to the namespace, the second refers to the class, then `gstream`, an inner class or something?

Comment: can I change the name of the root namespace rather

Comment: @vbNewbie: Yes you can, and perhaps will you have to change it throughout your code as well. That said, by opposition to C#, a VB.NET class should not contain any of the root namespace values, but only the specific namespace under which you wish to make your class into. If all of your classes in your library has the same namespace, then none of your classes shall contain the `Namespace` keyword. Otherwise, it gets concatenated. GPStream.GPStream.GPStream...